# Robust standard errors for mixed effects models in R

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, poisson-regression, robust-standard-error

I understand that you cannot fit a glmer(via "lme4") then test using robust SE estimator.

Ie

```
model <- glmer(Sepal.Length ~ Species * Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + (1 | grp), data = restricted2, family = poisson(link = "log"))
```

then do

```
coeftest(model, vcov = sandwich)
```

Is there any other packages that allow you to do the same using lme4 packages?

I've had a look at merDeriv package but I'm still not to sure how to go about this.

Also how would one calculate the relative risk from lme4 output?